# Laravel 4 - How do I submit a form to add comments to a page with a URL variable?

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, routes

I have a system where you go to http://example.com/restaurant/restaurant-key-example and you can view a given restaurant. I have a form at the bottom with reviews that can be added to the restaurant.

```
//Restaurant info page(GET)
Route::get('/restaurant/{key}', array(
    'as' => 'restaurant-show',
    'uses' => 'RestaurantController@getRestaurant'
));

//Restaurant review submit(POST)
Route::get('/restaurant/review/{key}', array(
    'as' => 'restaurant-review-post',
    'uses' => 'RestaurantController@postAddReview'
))->before('csrf');
```

`{{ Form::open(['route' => 'RestaurantController@postAddReview']) }}` and when I submit it, it goes to http://example.com/restaurant/key?restaurant-key-example. Is their any good way I can do this? What am I  doing wrong?
Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Not near enough code posted to help you here, too many missing parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First should never post any forms and data with GET, but POST. This means you have to rework your route to `Route::post('....');`

After that you dont need that parameter in there! In your method in that controller you need to check for all the inputs by this:

```
$inputs = Input::except('_token');
```

and var_dump it if you want to check what you have posted!

Regards and tell me if you need any further help!

Comment: Great thanks! I guess I was just digging myself deeper into trouble by trying to fix it, that's why I did the Route::get for the form handler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad i was able to help! Give me any feedback if you need further help! And dont foget to upvote ^_^